# Laravel - Passing POST data to view from controller

Tags: laravel, view, controller, request, laravel-blade

I have a selection of POST data (about 10 items) that I want to display on a summary page (blade).
I've managed to successfully get the **Request** object in to the controller where I can then access all the POST data.

```
public function summary(Request $request)
    {
        $var1 = $request->input('postdata1');
        $var2 = $request->input('postdata2');
        $var3 = $request->input('postdata3');
        $var4 = $request->input('postdata4');
        $var5 = $request->input('postdata5');   
        
        return view('planner_newsummary', compact('var1','var2','var3','var4','var5'));
    
    }
```

My question is, what is the best way to send all POST data from the **Request** object to the VIEW?

thanks
Craig.

Comment: `return view('planner_newsummary')->with($request->input())` will send everything in the `$request`'s `input` array as a variable, with matching name `$postdata1`, `$postdata2`, etc etc. Your current approach is fine, if not a little repetitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the request data in an array using:

```
$data = $request->all();
return view('planner_newsummary', $data);
```

([reference](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#input))

You can also exclude or only include certain data by using:

```
$input = $request->only(['username', 'password']);

$input = $request->only('username', 'password');

$input = $request->except(['credit_card']);

$input = $request->except('credit_card');
```

([reference](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-a-portion-of-the-input-data))

You can then pass this data into the view however you wish, once inside the view you can iterate through the list using blade using a for loop ([reference](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#loops)).

This will also will give you enough information regarding associative array loop in Blade. [Click](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/passing-arrays-to-blade-and-iterating).

If you need more clarification let me know,

Thanks,

Comment: I'm having issues retrieving the Request data in my View.. its an empty object @Jack

Comment: Hello @CraigJohnstone, is the data empty in the controller, view or both? If it is the view could you try this instead: `return view("planner_newsummary", ["requests"=>$data]);`. And then use $requests in the view. Thanks,

Comment: the issue is that Compact returns an array and I was trying to pull the data via  data->flyingFrom  (ie and object)

Answer (score -1):

Try doing this:

```
public function summary(Request $request)
    {
        $var1 = $request->input('postdata1');
        $var2 = $request->input('postdata2');
        $var3 = $request->input('postdata3');
        $var4 = $request->input('postdata4');
        $var5 = $request->input('postdata5');

        $data = ["var1" => $var1, "var2" => $var2,...]
        
        return view('planner_newsummary')->with($data);
    
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if this works too `return view('planner_newsummary', compact($data));` but try both ways